# What should I use as a dummy awaitable?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a Base class which provides a method with the following signature:

```
virtual async Task RunAsync()
```

Derived classes should override this implementation with something like

```
public override async Task RunAsync()
{
  await base.RunAsync();
  await this.DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Now the compiler gives me a warning that the Base.RunAsync is lacking an await statement. I want that my code is warning free, not suppressing warnings and that it runs without having to provide null checks even if the derived class doesn't provide an override implementation, therefore going with `virtual Task RunAsync()` (omitting the async keyword) is not possible.

For now the implementation in the base method is `await Task.Delay(0);` which dismisses the compiler warning, yet is somehow not "clean" in my opinion. What is the right way to cope with this subject?

Comment: Task.FromResult is probably what you are looking for

Comment: Or this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This seems like a funny implementation. Why not have `RunAsync` as a non-virtual method and create an `abstract` `RunAsyncInternal` method which `RunAsync` will call with `await` - this will also clear your warning.

Comment: Because I do not want to require derived classes to override the RunAsync. Or in other words: Somewhere there should be a method that just does nothing = Task.Delay(0). Defining an abstract method only moves the problem and doesn't solve it as it seems to me.

Comment: Writing dead dummy code that doesn't make any sense is **far** worse than suppressing warnings and giving an appropriate reason.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You misunderstand how `async` works. It's not part of the signature, so if you don't *need* the `await`, you don't actually have to use it. So even though you are providing a `Task RunAsync()` method, you can just write it *without* the `async`, for example:

```
virtual Task RunAsync()
{
  return Task.FromResult(false);
}
```

This still allows you to make an override that does in fact use `await`, like so:

```
override async Task RunAsync()
{
  await base.RunAsync();
  await DoSomeOtherStuffAsync();
}
```

This is the reason why the compiler gives you the warning - the `async` keyword *is completely useless*, and not part of the method signature. It's just a signal to the compiler that it's allowed to use the identifier `await` as a keyword, basically - to maintain backwards compatibility with older C# code.

**EDIT**:

As noted by Jeroen Mostert in the comments, from .NET Framework 4.6 on, the `Task.CompletedTask` property is public, so you can do this:

```
virtual Task RunAsync()
{
  return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

So if you can use 4.6+, this is the newest, cleanest option. And of course, if you need the task to actually return a value, `Task.FromResult` is still there :)

Comment: `Task.FromResult`was new to me. Still - and that's obviously not your fault - Task.FromResult(false) seems still like a workaround due to the const false used to call the method (comparable to Task.Delay(0) IMHO). However the framework does not offer something like `Task.FromResult`to provide a non-T task in its completed state. Would love to know @Eric-Lippert 's opinion/reasoning on that...

Comment: @David: The framework *does* offer that -- it's [Task.CompletedTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask).

Comment: Of course, I now see that's very, very recent -- from 4.6 onwards. Still, better late than never. :-)

Comment: Absolutely. Great! It's reason enough to move on to 4.6.

Comment: @David Well, it will *always* be a work-around - you're not doing any asynchronous work in an asynchronous method :D Both `Task.Delay(0)` and `Task.FromResult(false)` actually return a completed task immediately, so they are more or less equivalent (I avoid `Task.Delay(0)` - delay usually continues on a new thread unless called with `0`, so it can be a bit confusing). But yeah, now that `Task.CompletedTask` is public, there's no reason for using the other workarounds. If you can move to 4.6, go for it.